# Retain data after closing jetpack compose app

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to implement a custom settings page for my Compose application, but I could not find any standard way of saving data.

I have an option where the user can choose between light and dark theme within the app, but it is not retained after the app is closed.

I tried using `rememberSaveable` within my compsables, but they did not retain the data that was given to them.

My code looks something like this:

```
var darkTheme by remember { mutableStateOf(false) } // I need to save the value of this
Checkbox(checked = darkTheme, onCheckedChange = { darkTheme = !darkTheme })
```

Comment: "app is closed" - rememberSaveable won't survive this, use sharedPreference or a local database (room)

Comment: In addition to the comment above, you can also use ProtoDatastore, here's a [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-proto-datastore#0) and its [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore).

Answer (score 0):

Hey rememberSaveable will not work when the **App is Closed**. You can use  [sharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) [protoDatastore](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-proto-datastore#0) or local Database for this usecase.